# Javascript - Display image on form based on substring match in Folder

Tags: javascript, substring, directory, match, filenames

Going by what I've read so far this may not be possible with just Javascript.
I have a form in a GIS web based application called GeoMedia Smart Client.

I am trying to display an image on the form, but the first part of the file name must match the value in the ID_Counter field in the form. There may be more than one image that begins with this number - but I will deal with that later. So the url will be built with a substring match.

So far I have

```
IG.ImageLink = function() {
    var FeatName = 'vw_'+IG._form.id //the name of the GIS feature the form is showing, which is also the folder name.
    var IDCounter = IG._form.getItemById('ID_COUNTER').value();
    var src = "/website/TransientStorage/"+FeatName+"/"+IDCounter.match(IDCounter);

    show_image(src);
    }

function show_image(src) {
    IG._form.getItemById('IMAGETEST').value(src); //the image field on the form which displays the image.
}
```

I can get the url working by building a string and the image displays if I have the exact file name, but it would be good to build the string based on a substring match.

I hope that makes sense. Is this possible? Perhaps I need AJAX or JSON?

Comment: [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns an array. `IDCounter.match(IDCounter)` are you sure this is what you want to append to the `src`?

Comment: Hi RoyHowie. I want to match part of the file name to the ID_Counter, for example, the ID_Counter in the form may be 1234, and there may be a file in the folder called 1234_01052015.jpg. I want the url to return the file name based on the substring match. The next thing would be to look at situations where there is more than one file beginning with this number.

Comment: You should `console.log(IDCounter.match(IDCounter));` before the `var src = ...` line. My point was that you probably want to use `+ IDCounter.match(IDCounter)[someIndex]` instead of just `+ IDCounter.match(IDCounter)`, which is the same as `+ IDCounter.match(IDCounter).toString()`, which will produce something like `+ "[something,something,something]"`

Comment: Can I retrieve file names using Ajax if part of the name matches a value?

Comment: If you program your server to allow for that…